# Where should I put images files in React project?

Tags: reactjs

I usually make images folder under src folder, so I access them through require `require("images/sample.jpg")` in my components.

My friend who's learning React was struggling to load images and he made images folder under public like the below image. With that, he can access images without `require()`, so he just does `images/sample.jpg`. I thought I had it's required to use `require()` to load images in React.

Is there no problem to put images folder under public? then why should we use `require()`?

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Adding images in the public folder and the src folder both are acceptable methods, *however*, importing images into your component has the benefit that your assets will be handled by the build system, and will receive hashes which improves caching/performance. You'll also have the added benefit that it will throw an error if the file is moved/renamed/deleted.

I should note that I believe the hashing functionality is out of the box with create-react-app but needs to be manually configured in Webpack otherwise.

Comment: so using public folder won't have issues even though it's on production environment? The problem is missing performance efficiency?

Comment: I think it's pretty common practice to import your images into your components, delegating the public folder for stuff like favicons & other static content, etc. But outside of that, there shouldn't be any issues using the public folder.

Comment: Hi @KeithBrewster. I still don't understand where I should host my images. Do I should put them in an images folder inside the public folder, or not? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @PedroRelvas for me, I create a folder called `images` in my source folder and put all my images there. And I can import them with say

`import imageName from '../images/imageName.png'`

Comment: What if the images is used both in the app and also that end user could download all images from the public folder. Is there some workaround instead of having duplicate set of images?

Comment: if you can edit your answer, what is the best practice? saving images in public or under /src/assets/images

Answer (score 0):

I put it in the "public" as it's intended for static files, while "src" or "components", are viable solutions as well too.

I do think by putting it in src or component they have to be imported into the component and to be used, also this can increase build size as it's being processed by Webpack.